# Looping on objects // Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, map-function

I have a problem looping on object. I couldn't solve it. Please help me.

I am on a React project to improve my skill and gonna work with React Hooks.

There is a file like below which contains an object. I'm gonna fetch from an api.
I wanna to display the object details which i need on the page.

I've tried a lot of way to solve but they didn't work.

I am not adding all the codes what i tried but there is the simple one below which tells my goal. What is the correct solution to iterate on objects in React, JS ..

Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function ValueRef() {

    const myList = {
        "location_suggestions": [
          {
            "id": 61,
            "name": "London",
            "country_id": 215,
            "country_name": "United Kingdom",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_215.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 142,
            "state_name": "England and Wales",
            "state_code": "England and Wales"
          },
          {
            "id": 3454,
            "name": "London, ON",
            "country_id": 37,
            "country_name": "Canada",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_37.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 124,
            "state_name": "Ontario",
            "state_code": "ON"
          },
          {
            "id": 5836,
            "name": "London, KY",
            "country_id": 216,
            "country_name": "United States",
            "country_flag_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/countries/flags/country_216.png",
            "should_experiment_with": 0,
            "has_go_out_tab": 0,
            "discovery_enabled": 0,
            "has_new_ad_format": 0,
            "is_state": 0,
            "state_id": 85,
            "state_name": "Kentucky",
            "state_code": "KY"
          },
        ],
        "status": "success",
        "has_more": 0,
        "has_total": 0,
        "user_has_addresses": true
      }
   
    console.log(myList)

    return (
        <div>{
            Object.values(myList).map((detail)=>(<div>{detail}</div>))
        
        }</div>

    )
}
```

---

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, country_id,
country_name, country_flag_url, should_experiment_with, has_go_out_tab, discovery_enabled,
has_new_ad_format, is_state, state_id, state_name, state_code}). If you meant to render a collection
of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: do you want to iterate `myList.location_suggestions` or entire `myList` with `status,has_more...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are iterating over nested objects, that needs to be treated differently.

Oversimplifying your object, it is something like this :

```
const myList = {
        "location_suggestions": [ ...objects ],
        "status": "success",
        "has_more": 0,
        "has_total": 0,
        "user_has_addresses": true
      }
```

Now, when you do :

```
Object.values(myList).map((detail)=>(<div>{detail}</div>))
```

As you can see in your first iteration itself, the `detail` object contains an array, which is a type of object, that cannot be kept in a React render return.

There are 2 solutions to your problem,

1. Remove / skip the `location_suggestions` key to avoid the error.
2. Create a seperate iteration logic for `location_suggestions`

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it satisfactory